# How to Date field of datepicker non editable

Tags: datepicker, xamarin.forms, readonly

For Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker, the date field is "tappable" , the user can change the date after selecting it in the date picker. How to make the data field non-editable(read-only)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved when i added      Control.ShouldChangeCharacters += (field, range, replacementString) => false; to custom renderer file

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `IsEnabled=false`

```
<DatePicker IsEnabled="false"/>
```

[IsEnabled](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.IsEnabled/) is the property of `VisualElement` from which all controls are inherited.

It Gets or sets a value indicating whether this element is enabled in the user interface. This is a bindable property.

```
public Boolean IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

> true if the element is enabled; otherwise, false. The default value is
>   true.

If false, Elements are not enabled to participate in hit detection, and therefore will not receive focus or emit input events.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply , but i am afraid My requirement is different. I have to select a date from the picker, and after selecting it, the date field should not be modified further. now the selected date is editable.